# Is it possible to override the default value of a parameter in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-groovy

I have a Jenkins job with a single parameter that is triggered by the timer every 5 minutes. The default value of that parameter was initially set manually and I have to change it automatically from inside Jenkins (using a Groovy command I think). I have a script that triggers that job using Build With Parameters and the parameter sent by this script must be used for the following builds started by the timer.

For example, I have this string parameter with default value of 100:

[My String Parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m0R4P.png)

Using Build with parameters, the script passes 200 to the parameter:

[Build with parameters command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/huG7A.png)

Now the following builds started by the timer must use the value 200 given by the script.

Is it possible to override the default value of that parameter? I tried to use the EnvInject plugin but it didn't work. I also tried to use Groovy commands that I found on a YouTube tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k_ga9cXteVE), but I always get "unable to resolve class Jenkins".

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iu6W4.png)

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BzYRm.png)

Any help/advice would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: So you want a parameter value to become the new default value for all following builds?

Comment: Hi @zett42, exactly. That code in the image works, but the only problem was that I chose in jenkins "Execute groovy script" instead of "Execute system groovy script".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Solved] The problem was that I chose in jenkins "Execute groovy script" instead of "Execute system groovy script". There is a big difference between the two:

- Execute groovy script: it's like when you open cmd and write "groovy {some command}"
- Execute system groovy script: it has access to the entire JDK so it must be used for scripts

Probably Execute groovy script can also be configured to execute scripts, but I'm a beginner and I don't know how to do that yet :)

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to call a job on a time interval, with a different parameter value:

1. If you want to call the job with different values, that are static (e.g. the param value should alternate between 100 and 200, you know before hand that those are the only values you'll need) you can use the [parameterized scheduler plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/parameterized-scheduler-plugin). You would add a cron trigger to the job, and you'd configure a different interval for each input value.
2. If you want to evaluate a script and use its output to run the job, I would suggest you create another jenkins job, preferably a pipeline job, that runs on a timer, evaluates the script, and then calls the parameterized job using the `build job` [step](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-build-step/).

From your description, I think the second solution is more suitable to you.